# swap max and min in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, swap

I need to swap the max and min in a list of distinct numbers. Like so:

Example input

```
3 4 5 2 1
```

Example output

```
3 4 1 2 5
```

I figured using this would make the most sense:

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = min(a), max(a)
```

However, it seems to work on some lists of distinct numbers but not others (including the given example). I have no idea why. Can anyone see the bug?

Comment: Can you add an example where it is not working?

Comment: Calculate the indices first, otherwise you're recalculating `a.index(min(a))` *after you've written that value over `max(a)`*. This will fail for any input where the min appears after the max.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In multiple assignments, Python calculates all of the right hand side parts, left to right, then assigns them one by one to the left hand side parts, left to right (see [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) for details). So:

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = min(a), max(a)

a = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = 1, max(a)

a = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = 1, 5

a = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
a[a.index(5)], a[a.index(min(a))] = 1, 5

a = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
a[2], a[a.index(min(a))] = 1, 5

a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 1]
a[a.index(min(a))] = 5

a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 1]
a[a.index(1)] = 5

a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 1]
a[2] = 5
# ^ uh oh

a = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
```

If the minimum value is *before* the maximum value this works fine, because we always replace the first occurrence of the minimum value and that turns out to be the original one.

To fix it, just calculate the indices separately *before* doing the swap.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use this function to help you permuting min and max. In the distinct-list case, it'll work. If you have duplicates, it would also handle them.

```
def swap_min_max(l):
    max_value = max(l)
    min_value = min(l)

    # get all potential indices
    idx_min = [i for i,e in enumerate(l) if e==min_value]
    idx_max = [i for i,e in enumerate(l) if e==max_value]

    # replace values
    for idx in idx_min:
        l[idx] = max_value
    for idx in idx_max:
        l[idx] = min_value

    return l

>>>> swap_min_max([4, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1])
[4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5]

>>>> swap_min_max([3, 4, 5, 2, 1])
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: The question says: *I need to swap the max and min in a list of **distinct numbers***

Comment: That's right, my bad, I was a little too quick. Although *distinct numbers* is just a subcase of my answer -- which might still be useful, no ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution if number are distinct.

```
def swap(a) :
  max_index=a.index(max(a))
  min_index=a.index(min(a))
  ma=max(a)
  mi=min(a)
  a[max_index]=mi
  a[min_index]=ma
a=[3,4,5,2,1]
swap(a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is index no of max and min which you can find by index method:

```
data=[3,4, 5, 2, 1]

max_va=data.index(max(data))
min_va=data.index(min(data))

data[max_va],data[min_va]=data[min_va],data[max_va]

print(data)
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
```